# How to add custom menu in menubar in mac with electron?

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

I want to add custom menu in menu bar in mac with electron (nodejs)
eg. we have
[image]

and I want to add `filter menu` right after `Electron`.

Answer (score 11):

There's great documentation on building native, custom application menus in the [API docs here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/menu.md). There's lots of options and capabilities and platform differences.

For example, in your main process code you could do something like this:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
  mainWindow.loadURL(path.join('file://', __dirname, 'index.html'));
  setMainMenu();
});

function setMainMenu() {
  const template = [
    {
      label: 'Filter',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Hello',
          accelerator: 'Shift+CmdOrCtrl+H',
          click() {
              console.log('Oh, hi there!')
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(template));
}
```

That will create an application level menu with the label "Filter" and when opened will display the single menu item labeled "Hello". Clicking on it logs to the console.

Note that when you're using `electron-prebuilt`, it always say "Electron" in the top left. When you compile your app as a standalone application (not running through electron-prebuilt), it'll have your app name there.

As @neonhomer pointed out, this API has to be called after the ready event of app module.

I should also add that when using Electron in development, the default Electron app will provide a default menu for you (see https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/d26e4a4abf9dfc277974c6c9678a24a5f9e4d104/default_app/main.js#L48). When you package your app, that won't be there.

Comment: So far, this example has not worked for me on the Mac.Electron 1.2 on Yosemite.

Comment: It does not work, you show draw attention at @neonhomer answer:
"This API has to be called after the ready event of app module"

Comment: For making sure it works well in both Mac and Windows, please add the following to the function scope where you add the `template` menu:

```
    if(process.platform == 'darwin'){
        template.unshift({});
     }
```

Comment: I just want to add one menu item to the default menu... is there some way to do that without completely replacing it with an identical menu that I copy from the link you provided?

Answer (score 4):

There's a small note in the API documentation:
http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/#menusetapplicationmenumenu

> **Note**: This API has to be called after the ready event of app module.

Interesting that it works called directly in Windows.

Here's a simplified example:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron')

const menuTemplate = [...]
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate)

let win

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, })

    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
    createWindow()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit();
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

Comment: Something else interesting is that if a MenuItem is `visible: false` it still functions as a keyboard shortcut in Windows but does not on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

2019 Update: Can use this component:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-electron-titlebar